# Can I make a customized localization file in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

As the iOS have the localization ability, but I would like to have a special localized string, which is not include in the standard localization. May I implement the localized method to switch with localization file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use NSUserDeafaults?

In some view (maybe "myProperties") create an array with Localizations (maybe "English, Russian, German") and choose on of it.
Then, in some view6 where you need to set localization, take it from your properties...

oh, I think, each property contains different values of TimeInterval for localTimeZone, and maybe some button.textLabels for your localized design...

Sorry for my English ((